# How to implement Google+ login in C# >net

Tags: javascript, c#, google-api-js-client

I followed the procedures which google gave on its website like my HTML Code IS

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xasdas.apps.googleusercontent.com">
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script></head>
    ....
<body>
 <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" style="float:left;margin-left:30px;"></div>
</body>
```

then I am Using Java Script which is

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
         Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        alert("Rached Here");
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        alert("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
    };



        gapi.load('auth2', function () {
            alert("Reached Here1");
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '...apps.googleusercontent.com',

            });

            // Sign the user in, and then retrieve their ID.
            auth2.signIn().then(function () {
                var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
                alert("Reached Here");
                //facebook_authentication(profile.getName(), profile.getEmail());

            });

        });
```

It was working i mean some how i was getting the name and email id, But suddenly it stopped working. The Button is being converted to Signed in but i dont get any alert.

I just need name and email from this api, rest login portion is taken care by other part, but i am failing to get even these two.
What I need is:
If user is signed in i need to display name and email.
If he is not signed in show him dialogue box to sign in on g+ and then show his name and email.

Comment: I found it very complicated as well. There are thousands of articles, each on is almost different than the other. I'm still searching how to impmlemlent it right.